# Spring-data-jpa @OneToMany collection not populating

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm building the data layer for a new web app, using Spring Data (JPA flavor) and Hibernate.  I'm having a problem with the @OneToMany collections not populating on data load.   I've tried  FetchType.LAZY and FetchType.EAGER with no changes in result.  Are these annotations set up correctly?

Here's the parent class (edited for space):

```
public class AppMaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="APPLICATION_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
     private long ApplicationId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="appMaster")
     private Set<AppAddress> addresses = new HashSet<AppAddress>(0);
```

Here's the child class (also edited for space):

```
public class AppAddress implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
     private long addressId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="APPLICATION_ID", nullable=false)
     private AppMaster appMaster;
```

My data is generated and saved during the @Before setup part of the Junit test, and looks like this:

```
AppMaster table:  
    APPLICATION_ID=1

AppAddress table:
    ADDRESS_ID=1, APPLICATION_ID=1
    ADDRESS_ID=2, APPLICATION_ID=1
    ADDRESS_ID=3, APPLICATION_ID=1
    ADDRESS_ID=4, APPLICATION_ID=1
```

So I should be able to say

```
AppMaster master = appMasterService.findOne(1);  // Load existing record
assertEquals(4, master.getAddresses().size());   //  Loaded 4 dependent records
```

But when I do that I get this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :4
Actual   :0
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:472)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:456)
    at test.service.AppAddressServiceTest.setupData(AppAddressServiceTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Doesn't `mappedBy="AppMaster"` have to be `mappedBy="appMaster"`? Because that's the field name in the `AppAdress` class.

Comment: @obecker,  You're absolutely right - that was a typo induced by my previous editing.   I've fixed it in the example.   (Perils of posting redacted code.)   Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the original data was getting created and read inside the same transaction.   Since the data was never flushed to the actual data store at the end of the transaction, there was nothing for the JUnit test (which is where this problem showed up) to read.

The solution was to create the test data during the startup of the HSQLDB database in the spring test context.xml:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="testDataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="database/app_schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="database/app_data.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

That way when the JUnit tests start up, presto, there is already data there, waiting to be read.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled debug mode to show the sql generated? In Spring, it is showSQL=true.
Look at the SQL, it may offer some clues.